# Pourquoi les gens ne répondent pas avec "de rien" quand on leur dit "merci"

Tags: usage

Bonjour,

J'habite dans la petite couronne depuis pas mal de temps et j'ai remarqué que généralement les gens, soit au travail (Paris/IDF) soit ailleurs, ne disent pas "de rien", "je t'en prie", etc. quand je leur dis "merci".

Est-ce ça dépend de la région ou c'est quelque chose de commun ?

Comment: Ils ne répondent pas ou ils répondent autre chose ?

Comment: « De rien » est peut-être la moins usité des réactions à un « merci ». Ne rien dire est tout à fait une option, et ce n'est pas une question de français mais de savoir-vivre. Sinon il est fréquent de réagir par « y'a pas de quoi », « pas de soucis », « pas de problème(s) », « je vous(t') en prie »....

Comment: L'essentiel est, comme à New York, de ne pas [s'abstenir de dire merci](https://abc7ny.com/park-slope-stabbing-brooklyn-nyc-crime-nypd/12245907/).

Comment: @None pour la fréquence d'usage il nous faudrait des stats objectives. Personnellement j'utilise souvent "Plaisir", ou "Avec plaisir". Et plutôt d'accord que c'est surtout une question d'éducation et de politesse. Les parisiens ne sont pas réputés pour leur amabilité malheureusement.

Comment: @jlliagre ils ne répondent pas.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about the French language.

Comment: Je vis à Paris depuis plus de 50 ans ; effectivement on entend rarement un "De rien" ou "Je vous en prie". Je ne réponds pas à "Merci" ; ou alors, rarement, "y'a pas de quoi", qui sonne mal. A chaque fois que j'entends un "De rien", je me dis que je devrais le faire également, mais ça ne sort pas lorsque je suis en situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Merci*** n'appelle pas nécessairement une réponse. Un regard montrant qu'on a entendu le merci, un petit signe de tête peuvent parfaitement faire l'affaire.

Quand ce n'est pas le cas, j'ai souvent tendance à répondre ***De rien***, mais c'est peut-être un peu sous l'influence de l'espagnol chez qui j'avais trouvé le ***De nada*** généralisé bien pratique. À l'instar du ***Prego*** italien, Il m'arrive aussi de répondre ***Je t'en prie*** ou ***Je vous en prie*** dans des circonstances plus soutenues.

J'ai découvert la réponse très répandue dans la région toulousaine ***Avec plaisir*** mais je ne l'utilise pas.

D'autres formules plus régionales que l'on peut entendre sont ***S'il vous plait***, spécialement en Belgique et ***Bienvenue*** au Québec.

Une réponse courante et au sens similaire à ***De rien*** est ***Ce n'est rien***.

Une autre que me semble un peu surannée est ***Il n'y a pas de quoi*** ainsi que sa variante relâchée ***(Y'a) pas d'quoi***.

Si la situation s'y prête, on peux répondre ***C'est moi qui vous remercie*** ou juste ***C'est moi*** ainsi que ***Tout le plaisir est pour moi***.

J'entends parfois ***À votre service*** ou simplement ***Service*** pour montrer qu'on est là pour rendre service à la personne qui remercie.

Comme je l'ai écrit au début de ma réponse, le ton, l'intention et la communication non verbale sont plus à prendre en considération que la formule elle-même. Il est évident qu'une non-réponse accompagnée d'un sourire vaut largement mieux qu'un ***De rien*** bougon.

Comment: Par rapport (au fait) "que *merci* n'appelle pas nécessairement à une réponse". Est-ce que vous avez une référence qui la démontre ?

Comment: @NotCool N'appelle pas une réponse **verbale** aurais-je du écrire. Il suffit de montrer d'une façon ou d'une autre qu'on a entendu le merci et d'ailleurs à l'écrit, on ne répond pas nécessairement à un merci, sinon, ça n'en finirait plus...

Answer (score 0):

Lorsqu'on vous dit "Je vous remercie pour avoir fait cela", vous pouvez répondre "Je vous en prie" et c'est la réponse la plus correcte. Vous pouvez également dire "de rien" comme si l'on vous avait dit "Merci" et que vous répondiez "(Merci) de rien", car ce que vous avez fait vous semble vraiment peu ou bien parce que vous ne voulez pas embarrasser votre interlocuteur (qui vous est redevable de votre faveur).

La réponse "de rien" reste malgré tout assez familière et à la limite de la correction grammaticale.